# PS4 Data Transfer

Tags: ps4

I bought my PS4 from Argos 2 years ago with their 3 year warranty, my playstation has began to act up so i got into contact with them, they said they can try to fix it or send a replacement but i would need my old PS4 to do a data transfer to the new one. Is there a way of putting all my games and applications onto a USB and transferring that way ?

Answer (score 2):

Not via USB like that. You need both PS4s in working order (and hooked up) and use the PS4's built-in Data Transfer Utility. You'll need either both PS4s connected to WiFi or by a network cable for this to work.

If you ask them to fix your old PS4, then you'll want to backup your PS4 to an external hard drive, however PS4 backups can only be restored to the original PS4 (it is console locked).

Alternatively, backup your saves to USB, get a new PS4 and just redownload/install your games. I believe game saves aren't encrypted. If they are, you'll need PS+ to take advantage of PS+ cloud saves.

Comment: I believe that as long as both PS4's have the same PSN account, then USB transfer of Save Data should work.